# javafx multithreading does not run Webengine commands

Tags: multithreading, javafx

I am trying to fill a form which sometimes needs some waiting periods , so after a lot of search I was able to delay the execution of some commands (I had to create a separate thread to do that) and it worked fine but when I try to use commands from the `WebEngine` such as `executescript` it does not work.

here is my snippet :

**Note:** eng is a WebEngine instance and it is working fine outside the thread.

**Update:** After a small test I found out that the `eng` instance is working fine in the thread but I can not run `eng.executescript()`

**Update2:** after some search I found out that the eng.executescript has to run on the main thread , but in the same time I need to delay the execution for some time I'm not sure how I can do it.

```
Thread one = new Thread() {
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                System.out.println("Does it work?");
                                Thread.sleep(2000);
                                eng.executeScript("document.getElementById(\"textFieldId\").value = 100");
                                System.out.println("yup");
                            } catch(InterruptedException v) {
                                System.out.println(v);
                            }
                        }  
                    };

                    one.start();
```

Comment: To delay an action on the JavaFX Application thread you can use a [`Timeline`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) or a [`PauseTransition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html). If you continue to use a separate `Thread`, however, then you can simply call `eng.executeScript(...)` inside a [`Platform.runLater(Runnable)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater(java.lang.Runnable)) call.

Comment: Also, if you are delaying the action to run after the web page has fully loaded there is another way. You can listen to the [state property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/concurrent/Worker.html#stateProperty) of the `Worker` returned by [`WebEngine.getLoadWorker()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#getLoadWorker()). When the [`Worker.State`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/concurrent/Worker.State.html) changes to `SUCCEEDED` then the page has been successfully loaded.

Comment: @Slaw thank you for your answer , but that is not what I needed actually , so what I'm doing is that I have a browser and I'm trying to fill some html elements however there are some radio buttons when I switch them to some values they create another field , the process of creating this fields is as the following: the user switch to the trigger radio button , a request will be sent to the server , the server will response with the extra fields (HTML code). so the fields needs time to be loaded (the page will not be reloaded so the worker will not be a good help here)

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by implementing the waiting part by the javascript using `setTimeout` function , and it worked as a charm